# Thymeleaf PDF template parsing error when using fragment

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I'm trying to include a letter head in my PDF templates like so:

fragments/header.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Header</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header" class="clearfix" th:fragement="header(sender, name, address1, address2, today)">
    <div id="header-left">
        <img class="logo" src="app/src/main/resources/template/pdf/assets/logo.png"/>
        <div id="recipient">
            <p th:object="${sender}"><span th:text="*{name}"></span> - <span th:text="*{address1short}"></span> - <span th:text="*{address2}"></span></p>
            <p th:text="${name}"></p>
            <p>
                <span th:text="${address1}"></span><br/>
                <span th:text="${address2}"></span>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="header-right" th:object="${sender}">
        <p><strong th:text="*{name}"></strong></p>
        <p>
            <span th:text="*{address1}"></span><br />
            <span th:text="*{address2}"></span><br />
            <span class="label" th:text="*{phoneLabel} + ':'"></span><span th:text="*{phone}"></span><br />
            <span class="label" th:text="*{faxLabel} + ':'"></span><span th:text="*{fax}"></span><br />
            <span class="label" th:text="*{emailLabel} + ':'"></span><span th:text="*{email}"></span><br />
            <strong><span th:text="*{internetLabel}"></span>: <span th:text="*{internet}"></span></strong>
        </p>
        <p>
            <span th:text="*{court}"></span><br />
            <span th:text="*{registryNr}"></span><br />
            <span th:text="*{directorLabel}"></span>: <span th:text="*{director}"></span><br />
            <span th:text="*{vatId}"></span><br />
        </p>
        <p><span th:text="*{todayPrefix}"></span> <span th:text="${today}"></span></p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

template.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>Template</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="app/src/main/resources/template/pdf/assets/style.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div th:replace="app/src/main/resources/template/pdf/fragments/header :: header(${sender}, ${name}, ${address1}, ${address2}, ${today})"></div>

<!-- omitted for brevity -->

</body>
</html>
```

Everything works fine when I put the header code in the template directly. But when I try to inlude it as a fragment, like above, I get the following Error:

> org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "app/src/main/resources/template/pdf/fragments/header.html" - line 9, col 6)

template.html is in the app/src/main/resources/template/pdf/ folder. I had to include css and image files with the full path (from the root of the project) to get them to work. I tried including the fragment with the full path (as above) and only fragements/header, but I get the same error each time.

Im using

- spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf 2.1.1
- thymeleaf 3.0.11

Stacktrace:
[removed bc of character limit]

**UPDATE**

The correct path for the fragment is (in my case) "template/pfd/fragment/header" (so, full path from resources folder). Also, there was a typo in th:frag**e**ment="header".

Comment: Could you please post the complete stacktrace? And the fragment code, esp. line 9.

Comment: I added the stacktracktrace. fragment/header.html contains the complete fragment code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fragment reference should not be absolute to your project, but relative to your thymeleaf template root. So instead of (assuming it is `app/src/main/resources/template/` whre your thymeleaf templates are located)

```
th:replace="app/src/main/resources/template/pdf/fragments/header ..."
```

use

```
th:replace="pdf/fragments/header ..."
```

Comment: The correct path seems to be "template/pdf/fragments/header". With that I now get a different error. I updated it in my original post.

Comment: found my own typo XD (th:fragEment="header")

Answer (score 1):

The common use is

```
<div th:replace="fragments/header :: header"><div>
```

[Using Thymeleaf](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-thymeleaf-fragments)